Custom Tkinter Wait Variable Does Not Work
Currently, I am developing an application with Python 3 which uses Custom Tkinter in its GUI.
In this program, I need to create a wait for a button to be clicked.
I am able to do this is regular Tkinter, however when I try to do the same in custom Tkinter, it does not work.
In regular Tkinter the code for my particular problem is as follows:
import tkinter as tk

windowItem1 = tk.Tk()
windowItem1.title("Item1")
    
WaitState = tk.IntVar()
    
def submit():
    
    WaitState.set(1)
    print("submitted")
    windowItem1.destroy()
    
button = tk.Button(windowItem1, text="Submit", command=submit)
button.grid(column=0, row=1)
    
print("waiting...")
button.wait_variable(WaitState)
print("done waiting.")

I have attempted to recreate this in Custom Tkinter, as shown below:
windowItem1 = ctk.CTk()
windowItem1.title("Item1")
    
WaitState = ctk.IntVar()
    
def submit():
    
    WaitState.set(1)
    print("submitted")
    windowItem1.destroy()
    
button = ctk.CTkButton(windowItem1, text="Submit", command=submit)
button.grid(column=0, row=1)
    
print("waiting...")
button.wait_variable(WaitState)
print("done waiting.")

However, the window does not appear at all this time, and the console only displays "waiting..."
What is the solution to this issue?

There's no mainloop here.  No tkinter activity at all should take place until you start up your main loop.

Also, can't reproduce - your CTK code works fine for me. Maybe the window just appeared in a weird place?

I have included a mainloop and still there is definitely no window appearing at all.

@TimRoberts you don't always need mainloop. For example update in a while loop works the same way (not recommended though). Also wait_variable is the same as tcl's vwait which "enters the Tcl event loop, and events are processed". That means that it works the same as mainloop until the variable is modified.

Maybe simply call update once before the wait.

Note that customtkinter window is hidden initially until mainloop() is executed.  So try calling windowItem1.deiconify() before calling wait_variable().

@acw1668 I called windowItem1.deiconify() and it worked fine, thanks (I also had to remove the mainloop).
